# Do an intersect on a table and remove duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I'm making a dating app and running a script that will go through a likes table and find matches

Mark likes Mary

Mary likes Mark

This script will get these matches and insert a single copy of the match into another table along with null data which will be inserted at a later stage.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Matches] ( userA,userB,dateLocation,paidMale,paidFemale,[status],[timestamp])
Select ul1.[user],ul1.likes,'' AS dateLocation,'' AS paidMale,'' AS paidFemale,'' AS [status],GETDATE ( ) 
from [dbo].[Like] ul1 
intersect
Select likes,[user] 
from [dbo].[Like] ul2
```

The select statement gives me this. Obviously I have duplicate data and it doesn't matter which result I put in.

`user                                   likes
5DC89076-E554-42F2-A9AE-787B20F6F56B    9EF5B83E-319A-4E2F-88A1-E67227DBFDCE
9EF5B83E-319A-4E2F-88A1-E67227DBFDCE    5DC89076-E554-42F2-A9AE-787B20F6F56B`

I get an error 'must have an equal number of expressions' but obviously I don't what to insert all the data. How can I filter out the duplicates after I find the matches?

Comment: use INNER JOIN instead of INTERSECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select distinct case when l1.user < l1.likes then l1.user else l1.likes end,
    case when l1.user < l1.likes then l1.likes else l1.user end
from like l1
join like l2 on l2.user = l1.likes and l2.likes = l1.user
```

Comment: This statement only returns `5DC89076-E554-42F2-A9AE-787B20F6F56B`

Comment: Thanks a lot. My head was wrecked trying to figure this out.

Comment: I think this might be a better answer because your query doesn;t return column names

`SELECT l1.[user],l1.likes
FROM [dbo].[Like] l1
inner join [dbo].[Like] l2 on l2.[user] = l1.likes and l2.likes = l1.[user]
WHERE l1.[user] < l1.likes`

Comment: @user3922757, in this case you can use alias. Anyway, your answer is better :) Well done!